# jQuery slider-revolution images not displaying for MVC4 project

Tags: slider, carousel, jquery-easing

I am trying to set up a page with a slider control on the homepage. I designed the pages offline and they are working successfully with all the images working as expected but when I uploaded them to my MVC4 page the javascript arrow just keeps spinning and portions of the image are displaying but the ease in out functionality doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone have a look at my code and see if they can see where I am going wrong:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" id="view" content="width=device-width minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>MetaAwareness</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "@Url.Content("~/Content/meta-foundation.min.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "@Url.Content("~/Content/meta-style.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "@Url.Content("~/Content/meta-color.css")" title="color6" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "@Url.Content("~/Content/opensans_stylesheet.css")"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container region1wrap">
                <div class="row top_header">
                    <div class="eight columns">
                        <div class="login"> 
                            <a href="#" class="button" data-reveal-id="Login"><i class="icon-signin"></i>Login</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="login user-control"> You are not logged in!</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="four columns">
                        <div class="row collapse topheader-search">
                            <div class="eight mobile-three columns">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="four mobile-one columns"> 
                                <a href="#" class="button expand"><i class="icon-search"></i>Search</a> 
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container region2wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="three columns">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <a href="meta-index.html"><img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")" alt="MetaAwareness" title="MetaAwareness" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nine columns">
                        <nav class="top-bar">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="name"><h1><a href="#"> Please select your page</a></h1></li>
                                <li class="toggle-topbar"><a href="#"></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <nav>
                                <ul class="right">
                                    <li><a class="active" href="@Url.Action("Index")"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="meta-media.html"><i class="icon-laptop"></i>Media</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="meta-course.html"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Courses</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="meta-profile.html"><i class="icon-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contact")"><i class="icon-comments"></i>Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                             </nav>
                         </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </header>

    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>

    <!--Start of the footer section -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container region10wrap">
            <div class="row footer_bottom">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 MetaAwareness. All rights reserved.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <ul class="link-list">
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index")">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contact")">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Login" class="reveal-modal login-modal">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p>Please login using your credentials recived by email when you register.</p>
            <form>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="" />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="" />
                <p class="right"><a href="#">I forgot my password</a> | <a href="#">Resend activation e-mail</a></p>
                <input type="submit" class="medium button" value="Login!" />
            </form>
            <a class="close-reveal-modal"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a> 

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/foundation.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr.foundation.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/slider-revolution/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.3-packed.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/titan/js/jquery.titanlighbox.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/plugins/titan/js/prettify.js")"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/meta-app-head.js")"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script type="text/javascript"src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/meta-app.js")"></script>
    </footer>
</body>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="container region3wrap">
<div class="mainslider-container responsive">
    <div class="mainslider">
        <ul>
            <li data-transition="slotfade-horizontal" data-slotamount="10" data-thumb= "@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb0.jpg")"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb0.jpg")"/>
                <div class="caption lft" 
                    data-x="80" data-y="0" 
                    data-speed="900" 
                    data-start="900" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/pic_slider_2_1.png")" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfl" 
                    data-x="40" 
                    data-y="13" 
                    data-speed="900" 
                    data-start="1300" 
                    data-easing="easeOutBack"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/girl.png")" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption lft big_white" 
                    data-x="505" 
                    data-y="100" 
                    data-speed="400" 
                    data-start="1700" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">High Value, Comprehensive
                </div>
                <div class="caption lft big_cyan" 
                    data-x="505" 
                    data-y="144" 
                    data-speed="400" 
                    data-start="1900" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">E-learning Solutions
                </div>
                <div class="caption lft blue" 
                    data-x="505" 
                    data-y="186"
                    data-speed="400" 
                    data-start="2100" 
                    data-easing="easeOutBack">Inventore veritatis et quasi architecto <br />
                    beatae dicta sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis<br />
                    iste natus laudantium.
                </div>
            </li>

            <li data-transition="boxfade" data-slotamount="7" data-thumb= "@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb5.jpg")"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb5.jpg")" />
                <div class="caption sfb" 
                    data-x="0" 
                    data-y="0" 
                    data-speed="900" 
                    data-start="900" 
                    data-easing="easeOutSine"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/course-banner2.png")" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfb small_white" 
                    data-x="40" 
                    data-y="90" 
                    data-speed="600" 
                    data-start="1800" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">Kickstart Your
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfb medium_white" 
                    data-x="40" 
                    data-y="130" 
                    data-speed="600" 
                    data-start="2200" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">E-learning Experience
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfb large_white" 
                    data-x="40" 
                    data-y="185" 
                    data-speed="600" 
                    data-start="2600" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">TODAY...
                </div>
            </li>

            <li data-transition="curtain-3" data-slotamount="7" data-thumb="@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb2.jpg")"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/thumb2.jpg")" />
                <div class="caption lfl" 
                    data-x="35" 
                    data-y="0" 
                    data-speed="900" 
                    data-start="900" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"> <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Images/course-banner4.png")" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfr very_big_white" 
                    data-x="650" 
                    data-y="70" 
                    data-speed="300" 
                    data-start="1400" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">THE QUICKEST
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfr very_big_white" 
                    data-x="650" 
                    data-y="120" 
                    data-speed="300" 
                    data-start="1600" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">PATH TO
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfr very_big_white" 
                    data-x="650" 
                    data-y="170" 
                    data-speed="300" 
                    data-start="1800" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo">E-LEARNING
                </div>
                <div class="caption lfb big_white" 
                    data-x="660" 
                    data-y="230" 
                    data-speed="300" 
                    data-start="2000" 
                    data-easing="easeOutExpo"><a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
                </div>
             </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tp-bannertimer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to call the JqueryUI bundle and it was causing problems with IE although working with the rest of the top browsers